# Unable to migrate in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following database migration:

```
return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('metrics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

    });
}

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::create('metrics', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
          $table->dropIndex(['id']);
        });
    }
};
```

when i run the migration then

I get the following:

```
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'metrics' already exists (SQL: create table `metrics` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `value_string` varchar(255) null, `value_integer` int null, `value_float` double(8, 2) null, `value_date` date null, `value_boolean` tinyint(1) null, `category` varchar(255) not null, `source` varchar(255) not null, `availability` tinyint(1) not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }
```

I am confused as to what is causing the error and how to go about solving it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It means `metrics` table already created in your database. Please check your database, if you use XAMPP and phpMyAdmin, you can check it at `localhost/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1):

The table `metrics` that the migration is trying to create already exists in your database at the time the migration is running.

You will need to remove the table in order to run your migration.

The purpose if your migration is to create the `metrics` table, so typically the `down()` function would be used to drop that table from the database. It looks like you are instead trying to removing the index from the table (with incorrect syntax). I suggest modifying the `down()` function in your migration to:

```
/**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('metrics');
    }
```

This way, when/if you run `php artisan migrate:rollback` to reverse the migration, the table will be dropped from the database and you can re-run the migration avoiding the error your are reporting.

Answer (score 1):

the `metrics` table already exists in your database. First, you can remove this table change migration codes

```
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('metrics');
    }
```

so finally remove the table and run `php artisan migrate` command

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

simple works then migrate the tables